# Sombra por fora da div

Tags: css

Sempre usei sombra aos lados da div.
Mas é possível usar a sombra por fora (ou em cima) da div?

Como neste exemplo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse exemplo não está muito claro. Você quer que a sombra esteja dentro da div, de cima pra baixo?

Comment: "em cima" ou "por cima" do DIV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez o que você está procurando é o `box-shadow` com a opção `inset`.

Veja:

```css
.caixa{
    height: 150px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.sombra{
  box-shadow: 0 -45px 45px  red inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="caixa"></div>
<div class="caixa sombra"></div>
```

Normalmente, o `box-shadow` posiciona a sombra do lado de fora do elemento, mas com a opção `inset` a sombra se torna interna.

Answer (score 1):

Muito provavelmente isso é um elemento com dois `backgrounds`, um bg com a imagem e outro bg com o `linear-gradiente`.

Veja esse exemple e olhe como foi construído o `background` da `div`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.mapa {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), transparent), url(https://snazzy-maps-cdn.azureedge.net/assets/1243-xxxxxxxxxxx.png?v=20170626083204);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="mapa"></div>
```